# How to test java server without deployment?

Tags: java, webserver, client-server, server, web-deployment

Is there a way that I can test my java server on my computer without deploying it to a real server? I know php had wamp and lamp but what about java?

Comment: You can set up your server locally ? Which *java server* is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [Jboss(Wildfly)](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or any other application server. I think wamp or lamp has its own tomcat server you can use it to deploy java application.